# Posso usar empty e isset em uma variável?

Tags: php

Segue um exemplo:

```
if(isset($_POST['nome']) && !empty($_POST['nome'])) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['nome'] = $_POST['nome'];
}
```

[Ver `demonstração`](http://ideone.com/09MxuQ)

Caso eu não possa usar isto, qual seria o recomendado? Estou tentando adotar as melhores questões de segurança para meu site.

Citação interessante de uma referência exibida na resposta de @qmechanik:

> [`isset()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) testa se a variável foi "iniciada(*isset*)" e se não está *null*.
>
> [`empty()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) pode retornar "true" quando a variável foi "iniciada(*isset*) por certos valores.

**Lógica final**: `!empty` verifica se não está vázio, logo se não está vazio ele foi iniciado, portanto `!empty` já basta e não depende de `isset`, ao contrário do `isset` que depende do `!empty` (isto não remove o fato de poder colocar `isset` e `empty` em tal situação) em algumas situações, enfim qualquer pensamento ou citações que contradiz isto, por favor responda se possível, obrigado.

Comment: Qual é a intenção, em termos de segurança?

Comment: Qualquer cuidado é pouco, quero ter segurança em qualquer coisa pois minha web vai mecher com alguns dados pessoais e não quero que isto vaze para qualquer outro hacker que nao tem o que fazer..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Poder pode, mas é **redundante**.

Ambos tem diferentes objetivos, o [`empty`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.empty.php) determina se uma variável **está vazia** (uma *array vazia*, `FALSE`, `NULL`, *0* número ou no formato *string*), o [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.isset.php) por sua vez informa se uma variável **foi iniciada**, por exemplo, se uma variável é *nula* ou foi destruída com `unset`, o [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.isset.php) vai retornar `FALSE`. Um detalhe importante: ela não verifica se uma variável está **vazia**.

Utilizar os dois é *redundante*, basicamente o `empty` é uma abreviação para `!isset($variavel) || !$variavel`, `!empty()` é análogo à `isset($variavel) && $variavel`, mas sem emitir avisos, o manual do PHP cita:

> `empty()` é o oposto de (*boolean*) var, **com exceção de não gerar um
>   alerta (*warning*) se a variável não existir.**

O `empty` é implementado no arquivo [*zend_language_parser.y* - linha *1204*](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_language_parser.y#L1204) que executa o método `zend_compile_isset_or_empty` presente no arquivo [*zend_compile.c* - linha *6117*](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_compile.c#L6117), `empty` é praticamente um `!$variavel`. Esse é o ponto principal desta função: fazer uma comparação *booleana* sem ter a preocupação do conjunto ser variável ou não.

Se for para usar um ou outro, use o `empty`.

### Exemplo

```
$variavel;      // Variável indefinida
echo $variavel; // Notice: Undefined variable: variavel in...

if (!empty($variavel))
    echo "A {$variavel} pode ser usada, pois não está vazia ou indefinida.";
else
    echo "A variável está vazia ou não foi definida.";
```

[Ver `demonstração`](http://ideone.com/2VimAe)

O `isset` não foi necessário para verificar se a variável foi iniciada ou não.

Referências:

1. [Why check both isset() and !empty()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4559925/1608936)
2. [The empty($v) function is actually (!isset($v) || $v != true)-and-silence-warnings](http://www.phpsadness.com/sad/28)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta bem detalhada amigo, mas agora estou em dúvidas pois de acordo com o manual do php.net eu nao entendo nada sobre os exemplos :s e tem a resposta oposta do amigo ali :s

Comment: atualizado o #código, detalhes: isset = variavel foi iniciada, empty = a variavel nao está vazia, entao neste caso não ira dar qualquer tipo de erro, o amigo da outra resposta ali me traduziu e agr estou convertendo em pequenas formas. Mas irei tirar isto a limpo no meu xampp quando chegar em casa.

Comment: Tirei a limpo no ideone mesmo, confira: http://ideone.com/09MxuQ

Comment: Mas nao seria mais seguro isset e empty juntos?

Comment: @Kevinmtk O `empty` por si só já usa o `isset` internamente. Faça testes, olhe o código fonte, veja as referências. =)

Comment: Concordo com a lógica de que se a variável nao está vazia, logo ela foi iniciada anteriormente,  a nao ser que um hacker bugue isso...

Comment: @Kevinmtk Você mencionou na pergunta que estava preocupado com *segurança*, talvez esse [**link**](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/php-security-best-practices-tutorial.html) possa dar um início e esse [aqui](http://br.phptherightway.com/) também, *em português*. Sobre *boas práticas* [esse](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/php-as-10-melhores-praticas-pra-um-iniciante/) também é informativo. Qualquer dúvida crie uma pergunta. =)

Comment: Ok, obrigado pelas respostas, e pelo suporte rs, merece best answer amigo!

Answer (score 6):

Pode!
Você está verificando se uma variável existe e se possui algum valor.

Uma variável em *php* pode ser inicializada sem valor, portanto ela pode sim ser iniciada e não ter nenhum valor atrelado a ela, sendo assim existem vários casos onde você precisa verificar se a variável existe e se ela possui valor.

### Observação

No seu código você está verificando se existe **ou** está vazio, isso pode gerar um erro na verificação, pois a verificação do `isset()` está depois do `empty()`.

Portanto faça sua verificação assim para garantir o funcionamento do seu código:

```
$post = $_POST['nome'];

if(isset($post) && !empty($post)) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['nome'] = $post; 
}
```

> Note que eu utilizei `&&` no lugar de usar `||` assim eu preciso que a variável tanto exista quanto não esteja vazia.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta bem detalhada, e a correção do meu código exemplo. :D

Comment: muita gente está confusa em relação ao `empty`. em alguns casos é melhor utilizar somente o `empty`, mesmo que uma variável não exista!