# Quando devo usar empty ou isset?

Tags: php, empty

Percebi que algumas pessoas têm dúvidas a respeito da utilização dessas duas funções, ou se não têm dúvidas, parecem aplicar desnecessariamente uma dessas funções, sendo que em determinados casos a outra atende melhor.

Por exemplo, para verificar que um valor não existe ou se ele é falso, algumas pessoas fariam assim:

```
if ( ! isset($var) || $var == false)
{
   // Não existe ou é false
}
```

Sendo que poderia ser feito simplesmente:

```
if (empty($var)) {
  // Não existe ou é falsa
}
```

Pensando nesses tipos de complicações que geramos - digo em relação ao tamanho e complexidade de um código - resolvi elaborar essas perguntas.

- Em que casos, dos casos mais comuns, eu poderia utilizar `empty` ou `isset`, como maneira de simplificar a forma de verificar se um valor é realmente vazio?
- O que devo considerar quando utilizo a função `empty` para que não ocorrer condições indesejáveis para a lógica do código?

Para ajudar na pergunta, tenho casos de usos elaborados, para podermos aplicar as respostas - usando `empty` ou `isset`.

- Quero saber se determinado valor da variável `$_SESSION` existe, porém esse valor deve ser `true` (tanto faz se é `1` ou `true`, só precisa ser um valor equivalente a verdadeiro).
- Quero saber se um `array`de resultados de uma consulta ao banco veio como `array` vazio ou não.
- Quero saber se uma variável existe e se ela não tem o valor igual a `0`.

Comment: [Posso usar empty e isset em uma variável?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/64586/91)

Comment: Nesse caso fala do uso das duas (o que na maioria das vezes é desnecessários pelos códigos que contemplo)

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui, tem uma tabela que mostra o que cada uma faz de diferente: https://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/php-isset-vs-empty-vs-is_null/

Comment: `is_null` eu utilizaria apenas para callbacks, como `array_filter`. Para verificação "na unha" acho desnecerrário;

Comment: Pra quem diz que `empty` não verifica variável inexistente : http://ideone.com/iP6V64

Comment: Creio que isso já foi respondido: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/89960/como-validar-cada-tipo-de-dado-recebido-de-um-formul%C3%A1rio?noredirect=1#comment182108_89960

Answer (score 7):

Os próprios nomes das funções já dizem tudo, isset() para checar se realmente a variável está definida e prevenir erros, empty() é complicado, para você realmente saber se um valor é vazio (sem espaços, null, etc), você sempre deve tratar a variável, eu recomendo sempre o uso desta lib https://github.com/Respect/Validation isto responde suas duas primeiras questões, vamos as próximas:

> Quero saber se determinado valor da variável $_SESSION existe, porém
>   esse valor deve ser true (tanto faz se é 1 ou true, só precisa ser um
>   valor equivalente a verdadeiro).

```
isset($_SESSION['var']) && $_SESSION['var'] === true
```

> Quero saber se um arrayde resultados de uma consulta ao banco veio
>   como array vazio ou não.

```
is_array($var) && !empty($var)
```

> Quero saber se uma variável existe e se ela não tem o valor igual a 0

```
isset($var) && $var === 0
```

Answer (score 4):

Para resumir, aqui está exatamente o que você precisa saber.
Onde estiver vazio, retornará `bool(false)`:

```
| valor com variável ($var) | isset($var) | empty($var) | is_null($var) |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| "" (string vazia)         | bool(true) | bool(true)   |               |                |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++   
| " " (espaço)              | bool(true) |              |               |   
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++   
| FALSE (boleano)           | bool(true) | bool(true)   |               |   
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++   
| TRUE  (boleano)           | bool(true) |              |               |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++   
| array() (vetor vazio)     | bool(true) | bool(true)   |               |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++   
| NULL (nulo)               |            | bool(true)   | bool(true)    |   
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++   
| "0" (0 como string)       | bool(true) | bool(true)   |               |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++   
|  0 (0 como inteiro)       | bool(true) | bool(true)   |               |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++   
| 0.0 (0 como um float)     | bool(true) | bool(true)   |               |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++   
| var $var; (a variável     |            |              |               |
|            declarada      |            | bool(true)   | bool(true)    |
|       sem definir valor)  |            |              |               |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++   
| NULL byte ("\ 0")         | bool(true) |              |               |   
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Answer (score 4):

Bom, para isso vou selecionar, e responder as perguntas uma a uma.

> **Em que casos, dos casos mais comuns, eu poderia utilizar empty ou isset, como maneira de simplificar a forma de verificar se um valor é realmente vazio?**

Quanto a isso é realmente um bocado complicado explicar, até porque normalmente *vazio* pode ter vários significados, desde *"vago" a "oco"*. No *PHP* e noutras linguagens, a lógica e o significado é o mesmo.

> **O que devo considerar quando utilizo a função empty para que não ocorrer condições indesejáveis para a lógica do código?**

A única coisa que deves considerar quando utilizas a função `empty()`, é que a variável, ou o retorno esperado tenha valor *[nulo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o%29) (NULL)*.

> **Para ajudar na pergunta, tenho casos de usos elaborados, para podermos aplicar as respostas - usando empty ou isset.**

`isset()` Simplesmente verificas se o valor existe, ou se está definido que praticamente a mesma coisa, verificas se aquele determinado resultado existe, nada mais que isso. Equivale a algo que pode ser medido, ou causar alterações.

> **Quero saber se determinado valor da variável $_SESSION existe, porém esse valor deve ser true (tanto faz se é 1 ou true, só precisa ser um valor equivalente a verdadeiro).**

Utilizando o *isset()* consegues verificar se essa mesma sessão já foi inicializada, ou ainda verificar se possui algum valor.

> **Quero saber se um array de resultados de uma consulta ao banco veio como array vazio ou não.**

Para *array* pode-se utilizar o `empty()`, porque normalmente quando um(a) *array* vem sem qualquer valor, logo, enquadra na categoria de *vazio*, simples.

> **Quero saber se uma variável existe e se ela não tem o valor igual a 0.**

Para isso, deves usar ambas, primeiro verificas se a variável recebeu algum valor, apesar de *0*, zero é uma existência nula *(O.o)*, pois é, e depois deve-se então verificar se o seu valor é ou não nulo.

**Alguns exemplos de valores nulos**

```
$var = ""; # String vazia é NULL mas para o isset() está definida por ser String
$var = null; # null é NULL
$var = 0; # Zero é NULL
$var = 0.0; # 0.0 é NULL
$var = "0" # String 0 é NULL
$var = false; # é NULL
$var = array(); # Array vazia é NULL
Bits\Bytes Nulos também contam, é possível observar isso nalguns exemplos aqui
```

**NOTA:** Podes sempre ler a minha resposta, no *link* nas referências, lá expliquei também um pouco sobre valores nulos, e tipos de verificações.

---

## Referências:

Com base no que acabei de responder, pode ser que ainda restem algumas dúvidas, lá isso é compreensível, porque trabalhar com valores deste tipo e funções semelhantes às vezes é confuso, contudo, recomendo que continues a procurar por outras definições, ou explicações de pessoas diferentes, de modo a chegares a um conclusão, se achares que estas não são suficientes. Aprender baseia-se nisso.

[NULL (NULO) - Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o%29)

[Como validar cada tipo de dado recebido de um formulário?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/89960/como-validar-cada-tipo-de-dado-recebido-de-um-formul%C3%A1rio?noredirect=1#comment182108_89960)