# Erro no isset PHP

Tags: php

Está dando erro quando utilizo o isset com os métodos novos do PHP:

```
<?php
require './fb.php';
if (isset(filter_input(INPUT_SESSION, "fb_access_token")) && !empty(filter_input(INPUT_SESSION, "fb_access_token"))):
    echo "Ta logado!";
else:
    header("Location: login.php");
endif;
```

---

```
Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead) in C:\wamp64\www\bw7\index.php on line 9
```

Ja utilizando variaveis globais, funciona:

```
<?php
require './fb.php';
if(isset($_SESSION["fb_access_token"])):
    echo "Ta logado!";
else:
    header("Location: login.php");
endif;
```

Por que?

Comment: Não pode usar `isset()` em expressões, pode trocar por `empty()` caso a versão do php seja a 5.5 ou superior.

Comment: Mas o filter_input(INPUT_SESSION, "fb_access_token") não faz a mesma coisa do $_SESSION["fb_access_token"])?

Comment: Acabei de ver que o INPUT_SESSION não foi implementado ainda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`isset()` não foi feita para ser usada com expressões, a documentação diz qual é o proposito.

> Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL.

Tradução:

> Determinada se a **variável** está setada e não é nula.

Não faz sentido um código como

```
isset(count(false));
```

`empty()` a partir do php5.5 suporta expressões então nesse caso é o mais adequado. Se quer verificar se existe algo na sessão vá direto ao ponto com:

```
if(!empty($_SESSION["fb_access_token"])){
   echo 'logado';
}else{
    header("Location: login.php");
}
```

**Relaciondas:**

[Posso usar empty e isset em uma variável?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/64586/91)

[Quando devo usar empty ou isset?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91243/91)

Answer (score 3):

É por causa da expressão, tente fazer desta forma:

```
<?php
require './fb.php';
if (isset(filter_var("fb_access_token")) && !empty(filter_var("fb_access_token"))):
    echo "Ta logado!";
else:
    header("Location: login.php");
endif;
```