# Notice: Undefined index - erro ao tentar realizar um $_POST no controller (MVC)

Tags: php, javascript, mvc

Estou tentando fazer um combobox dinâmico com html, php e javascript.

Para isso, preciso enviar o valor selecionado no primeiro select (View) para meu arquivo Controller, mas o seguinte erro ocorre:

**Notice: Undefined index: categid in C:\xampp2\htdocs\testes\catalog\controller\account\customerpartner\addproduct.php**

Alguém poderia me ajudar a resolver esse erro? Seguem os códigos.

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

         $("select[name=product-category]").change(function(){
            $("select[name=product-subcategory1]").html('<option value="">Carregando...</option>');

            $.post("catalog/controller/account/customerpartner/addproduct.php",
                  {categid:$(this).val()},
                  function(valor){
                     $("select[name=product-subcategory1]").html(valor);
                  }
                  )

         })
      })

</script>
```

**PHP**

```
if ($_POST["categid"]) {
    $categid = $_POST['categid'];
}
```

Agradeço desde já a ajuda.

Comment: Leitura recomendada => [Posso usar empty e isset em uma variável?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/64586/91) e [Quando devo usar empty ou isset?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91243/91)

Comment: tenta usar `if (isset($_POST["categid"]))`

Comment: Já tentei usar 
if (isset($_POST["categid"])){
    echo $_POST["categid"];
}else{
    echo "falha";
}
mas falha do mesmo jeito.